# js 'onclick' has no response, same code but wont work

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){

             var color = document.getElementsByName("color");

             var checkedAllBtn = document.getElementById("checkedAllBtn");
             checkedAllBtn.onclick = function(){
                 
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = true;
                 }
             };

             var checkedNoBtn = document.getElementById("checkedNoBtn");
             checkedNoBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = false;
                 }
             };

             var checkedRevBtn = document.getElementById("checkedRevBtn");
             checkedRevBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = !color[i].checked;
                 }
             };

             var sendBtn = document.getElementById("sendBtn");
             sendBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                    if(color[i].checked){
                         alert(color[i].value);                   
                     }
                 }
             };

             var checkedAllBox = document.getElementsById("checkedAllBox");
             checkedAllBox.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                    color[i].checked = checkedAllBox.checked;
                 }
             };

             for(var j = 0; j<color.length; j++){
                if(!color[i].checked){
                    checkedAllBox.checked = false;
                    break;
                }
             }


        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Red">
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Yellow">
    <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Green">
    <label for="test3">Green</label>
  </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Brown">
      <label for="test4">Brown</label>
  </p>
</form>

<button id="checkedAllBtn">Select All</button>
<button id="checkedNoBtn">Unselect All</button>
<button id="checkedRevBtn">Inverse</button>
<button id="sendBtn">Submit</button>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkedAllBox">
<label for="test5">Select All</label>

</body>
</html>
```

js 'onclick'(checkedAllBox)is not working, I can only copy the last section code and change keywords to make it work, if I type it one by one, the function just has no response.

And also the color of 'onclick' in vscode is different.
The not working one is blue, all others are red.
When I move my mouse to all others 'onclick', it shows"
(property) GlobalEventHandlers.onclick: (this: GlobalEventHandlers, ev: MouseEvent) => any
"
But when I move my mouse to checkedAllBox.onclick it only shows"any"

Comment: var checkedAllBox = document.getElementsById("checkedAllBox"); should be              var checkedAllBox = document.getElementById("checkedAllBox");.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- IDs must be unique, and as such, `document.getElementsById` would not make any sense. Use `document.getElementById` instead
- You are referencing the wrong index in your `for` loop; `i` should be `j`

Try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        window.onload = function(){

             var color = document.getElementsByName("color");

             var checkedAllBtn = document.getElementById("checkedAllBtn");
             checkedAllBtn.onclick = function(){
                 
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = true;
                 }
             };

             var checkedNoBtn = document.getElementById("checkedNoBtn");
             checkedNoBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = false;
                 }
             };

             var checkedRevBtn = document.getElementById("checkedRevBtn");
             checkedRevBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                     color[i].checked = !color[i].checked;
                 }
             };

             var sendBtn = document.getElementById("sendBtn");
             sendBtn.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                    if(color[i].checked){
                         alert(color[i].value);                   
                     }
                 }
             };

             var checkedAllBox = document.getElementById("checkedAllBox");
             checkedAllBox.onclick = function(){
                 for(var i =0; i<color.length; i++){
                    color[i].checked = checkedAllBox.checked;
                 }
             };

             for(var j = 0; j<color.length; j++){
                if(!color[j].checked){
                    checkedAllBox.checked = false;
                    break;
                }
             }


        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Red">
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Yellow">
    <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Green">
    <label for="test3">Green</label>
  </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="Brown">
      <label for="test4">Brown</label>
  </p>
</form>

<button id="checkedAllBtn">Select All</button>
<button id="checkedNoBtn">Unselect All</button>
<button id="checkedRevBtn">Inverse</button>
<button id="sendBtn">Submit</button>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkedAllBox">
<label for="test5">Select All</label>

</body>
</html>
```